# how to solve django: UnboundLocalError

Tags: django, view, django-views, formset

I have the given view and template code, when i try to run this code i get the following errors.when i searched about this type of error,i found that it happens when a variable and function is given the same name,but could't correct it in my code.

```
 Environment:

 Request Method: GET
 Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/budget/show/
 Django Version: 1.2.5
 Python Version: 2.7.1
 Installed Applications:
 ['django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'mysite.bug']
  Installed Middleware:
  ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


 Traceback:
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args,   **callback_kwargs)
    File "/home/nimesh/budman/mysite/../mysite/bug/views.py" in shown 252.             
    return render_to_response('budgetfinalform3.html', {'account_number': c,'period':d,'month':e,'year':f,'formsetlist': formset,'child':child},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

     Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /budget/show/
     Exception Value: local variable 'formset' referenced before assignment
```

plz help me to remove this error.

```
def show (request):
b = request.session["s1"]
c = request.session["s2"]
d = request.session["s3"]
a = account_period.objects.filter(year=d).values('id')
e = account_period.objects.filter(year=d).values('month')
f = account_period.objects.filter(id = a).values('year')

try:
        child = account_tab.objects.filter(parent_account_number=c).values('account_number')
        noofchild = account_tab.objects.filter(parent_account_number=c).count()
except account_tab.DoesNotExist:
        noofchild = 0
if noofchild != 0 :   
       formsetlist = []


       for i in range(0, noofchild):
        formsetlist.append(formset_factory(bu, extra=b))
    if request.method == 'POST':

     formsetlist2.append(formsetlist[i](request.POST))

     if formsetlist2[i].is_valid():
       j=0
       for form in formsetlist2[i].forms:
         z = account_tab.objects.get(account_number = child[i:(i+1)])
         x = form.cleaned_data['value']
         y = account_period.objects.get(id=a[j:(j+1)])
         try:
                uip = budget.objects.get(account_no = child[i:(i+1)],account_period = a[j:(j+1)])
                if uip.budget_amount != x:

                  uip.budget_amount = x
                  uip.save()

         except budget.DoesNotExist:

                w = budget(account_no = z, account_period = y, budget_amount = x, created_by_login = 'me')
                w.save()
         j=j+1
       pass
       return HttpResponse('thanks')


    else:
             return render_to_response('budgetfinalform3.html', {'account_number': c,'period':d,'month':e,'year':f,'formsetlist': formset,'child':child},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
     #return HttpResponse(mes)
```

Template code is

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>BUDGET</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>BUDGET MANAGEMENTS</h1>
    <h2>Your Account Number is : {{ account_number }}.</h2> <h2>You Chose {{ period }} {{month}} as period</h2>   

    {% if form.errors %}
    <p style="color: red;">
        Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
    </p>
    {% endif %}


    <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for formset in formsetlist %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{child}}

    <table>
    {% for form in formset.forms %}

    {% if forloop.counter == 0  %}
     {{child.1}}
    {% endif%}
    {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>   
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please fix your indentation and formatting. and include a bit more of the error output

Comment: @scytale       i have given the error info and tried to indent the code (plz bear with me im a beginner)

Comment: your indentation in the view is *still* messed up. please fix it as a courtesy to the people who you are asking to help you. it sounds like your template variables are not being set properly. put some print statements into your view to see if the `formsetlist` is being populated correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return render_to_response('budgetfinalform3.html', {'account_number': c,'period':d,'month':e,'year':f,'formsetlist': formset,'child':child},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Uses `formset` but it looks/sounds like you meant `formsetlist`:

```
return render_to_response('budgetfinalform3.html', {'account_number': c,'period':d,'month':e,'year':f,'formsetlist': formsetlist,'child':child},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: when i make the change u suggested,i get a webpage with no forms and fields.

Comment: Then, you have *another* problem, but this solves the `UnboundLocalError` issue. Accept Barnaby's answer and open a new question if you're having other problems.